# Source for Semi-structures in algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I would like to read about the abstract theory of some semi-algebraic structures, more explicitly:

- Semi-groups
- Semi-rings
- Semi-modules
- Semi-vector spaces.

I would prefer, if it is a book and that is easily accessible, but I am not bounded in these options. The more suggestions, the better.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See also [Semi-algebraic geometry](https://www.math.princeton.edu/events/introduction-semialgebraic-geometry-2016-03-31t163003).

Comment: There is in my opinion no connexion between semi-groups and semi-rings, except the fact that they are weak versions of classical structures, so people put a "semi" in front of the name. On the other hand semi-modules and semi-vector spaces are related to semi-rings.

Comment: It's likely best to pick one area to study and follow through on that, e.g sem-groups.  Lots to learn, and little synergy from combining it with semi-rings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A book that covers semi-groups, semi-rings and semi-modules (and semi-fields) very well is Hanns Joachim Weinert's book "Semirings: Algebraic Theory And Applications In Computer Science". It provides a gentle introduction and exercises including selected solutions. The outline is given by the following TOC:

[TOC of "Semirings: Algebraic Theory And Applications In Computer Science"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dh0C6.png)

An excerpt PDF (TOC, Notation, Bibliography) of the AMS book "The Algebraic Theory of Semigroups" by Clifford and Preston is publicly available:
[The Algebraic Theory of Semigroups](https://www.ams.org/books/surv/007.1/surv007.1-endmatter.pdf) and covers the topic of semi-groups very well (semi-rings, semi-modules and semi-fields lie not in the scope of this book).